# ¿Como no imprimir valores repetidos?

Tags: php, php7, php5

Tengo un código, en donde llamo a una función creada en PHP y hago su recorrido en forma de matriz. La idea es poner las iniciales de roles en una matriz (tipo batalla naval), pero existen muchos elementos que poner en un solo cuadrante y la idea es evitar que se repitan algunos valores (ej. RRRRRACRAAA) en el mismo cuadrante y solo se imprima una sola ocacion (ej. RAC)

```
foreach($raci as $ra){
          $roles = $obj_rac->rol_roles($ra->posicion, $nombre_proceso);
                                    ?>
                                    <td>
                                    <ul>
                                        <?php
                                        
                                        foreach($roles as $key => $rol)
                                        {
                                            $rol1 = $rol->rol;
                                            $rol1 = substr($rol1,0,1);
                                            $color = '';
                                            if($key > 0) $color = 'color: red;';
                                               
                                                ?>
                                                <li style="list-style: none;<?=$color;?>"><?=utf8_encode($rol1);?></li>
                                                <?php
                                           
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                        </ul>
                                    </td>
                                    <?php
                                }
                                ?>
```

Después de varios intentos por querer evitar que imprima 'n' veces un valor solicito de alguna persona que pueda auxiliarme con este detalle.

Answer (score 0):

En `Php` existe una función que elimina los duplicados de cualquier arreglo, se llama `array_unique`.

Ejemplo:

```
$a = array("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C");

print_r(array_unique($a)); // Imprimirá Array ( [0] => a [3] => b [5] => c )
```

Puedes intentar eliminar los duplicados del arreglo y despues recorrerlo; de esa manera te aseguras que no se imprimirán repetidos.